# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter for use in a messaging app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have scoured the documentation for FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and related classes, but cannot find a way to do what I want (without rebuilding the library myself).

I am working on an app that has built in messaging (both group, and direct messaging other users).

Group chat works, because it pulls every message from the database reference under the group chat node.

Direct messages are being tricky. I want to skip the nodes from the reference that do not contain a model ID of the current user, and the user they are trying to message (so that they cannot see other peoples messages).

In the code below, I am trying to return null if the viewType = 10, because I do not want that chat bubble to show...as you would expect, I get a null pointer exception from the RecyclerViewAdapter class.

I know WHY I am getting the error. I am intentionally passing null to it, in an attempt to skip (or iterate over the current item), without displaying the chat bubble in any position.

Here is my firebase structure (exported JSON): [Database Structure](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-G9lr-KK14fMHE4ZDZCcWNlbDQ)

Here is a stack trace for reference purposes:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.aztechdev.squad, PID: 21249
                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.mItemViewType' on a null object reference
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6368)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5555)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:570)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3312)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3844)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                     at com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.FlowingDrawer.onLayout(FlowingDrawer.java:138)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1795)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                     at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1197)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131)
                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1391)
                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:870)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1193)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
09-02 10:47:22.899 21249-21249/com.aztechdev.squad E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:726)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2346)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2068)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Here is my FirebaseRecyclerAdapter:

```
package com.aztechdev.squad.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.aztechdev.squad.helpers.common;
import com.aztechdev.squad.model.DirectChatModel;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library.Helper.EmojiconTextView;

import com.aztechdev.squad.R;


public class DirectFirebaseAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DirectChatModel,DirectFirebaseAdapter.MyChatViewHolder> {

private static final int RIGHT_MSG = 0;
private static final int LEFT_MSG = 1;
private static final int RIGHT_MSG_IMG = 2;
private static final int LEFT_MSG_IMG = 3;

public static final String TAG = "DirectFirebaseAdapter";
private ClickListenerChatFirebase mClickListenerChatFirebase;

private String mUID;
private Context mContext;

public DirectFirebaseAdapter(Context context, DatabaseReference ref, String mUID, ClickListenerChatFirebase mClickListenerChatFirebase) {
    super(DirectChatModel.class, R.layout.item_message_left, DirectFirebaseAdapter.MyChatViewHolder.class, ref);
    this.mUID = mUID;
    this.mClickListenerChatFirebase = mClickListenerChatFirebase;
    this.mContext = context;

}


@Override
public MyChatViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    if (viewType == RIGHT_MSG){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_message_right,parent,false);
        return new MyChatViewHolder(view);
    }else if (viewType == LEFT_MSG){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_message_left,parent,false);
        return new MyChatViewHolder(view);
    }else if (viewType == RIGHT_MSG_IMG){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_message_right_img,parent,false);
        return new MyChatViewHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == 10) {
        return null;
    } else {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_message_left_img,parent,false);
        return new MyChatViewHolder(view);
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    DirectChatModel model = getItem(position);

    Log.d(TAG, "getItemCount: " + getItemCount());
    Log.d(TAG, "From UID: " + model.getFrom().getId());
    Log.d(TAG, "To UID: " + model.getTo().getId());


    **if (!model.getFrom().getId().equals(mUID) && !model.getTo().getId().equals(mUID)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getItemViewType: UID not found");
        return 10;
    }**


    if (model.getMapModel() != null){
        if (model.getFrom().getId().equals(mUID)){
            return RIGHT_MSG_IMG;
        }else{
            return LEFT_MSG_IMG;
        }
    }else if (model.getFile() != null){
        if (model.getFile().getType().equals("img") && model.getFrom().getId().equals(mUID)){
            return RIGHT_MSG_IMG;
        }else{
            return LEFT_MSG_IMG;
        }
    }else if (model.getFrom().getId().equals(mUID)){
        return RIGHT_MSG;
    }else {
        return LEFT_MSG;
    }
}

@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(MyChatViewHolder viewHolder, DirectChatModel model, int position) {

    if (model.getTo().getId().equals(mUID)) {
        viewHolder.setIvUser(model.getTo().getPhoto_profile());
        viewHolder.setTvTimestamp(model.getTimeStamp(), model.getTo().getName());

    } else {
        viewHolder.setIvUser(model.getFrom().getPhoto_profile());
        viewHolder.setTvTimestamp(model.getTimeStamp(), model.getFrom().getName());

    }

    viewHolder.setTxtMessage(model.getMessage());
    viewHolder.tvIsLocation(View.GONE);
    if (model.getFile() != null){
        viewHolder.tvIsLocation(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.setIvChatPhoto(model.getFile().getUrl_file());
    }else if(model.getMapModel() != null){
        viewHolder.setIvChatPhoto(common.local(model.getMapModel().getLatitude(),model.getMapModel().getLongitude()));
        viewHolder.tvIsLocation(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}


public class MyChatViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView tvTimestamp,tvLocation;
    EmojiconTextView txtMessage;
    ImageView ivUser,ivChatPhoto;

    public MyChatViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvTimestamp = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        txtMessage = (EmojiconTextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        tvLocation = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
        ivChatPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_chat);
        ivUser = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivUserChat);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        DirectChatModel model = getItem(position);
        if (model.getMapModel() != null){
            mClickListenerChatFirebase.clickImageMapChat(view,position,model.getMapModel().getLatitude(),model.getMapModel().getLongitude());
        }else{
           // mClickListenerChatFirebase.clickImageChat(view,position,model.getUserModel().getName(),model.getUserModel().getPhoto_profile(),model.getFile().getUrl_file());
        }
    }

    public void setTxtMessage(String message){
        if (txtMessage == null)return;
        txtMessage.setText(message);
    }

    public void setIvUser(String urlPhotoUser){
        if (ivUser == null)return;
        CircleTransform circleTransform = new CircleTransform();
        GlideApp.with(ivUser.getContext()).load(urlPhotoUser).centerCrop().transform(circleTransform).override(160,160).into(ivUser);

    }

    public void setTvTimestamp(String timestamp, String sender){
        if (tvTimestamp == null)return;
        tvTimestamp.setText(sender + " - " + convertTimestamp(timestamp));
    }

    public void setIvChatPhoto(String url){
        if (ivChatPhoto == null)return;

        GlideApp.with(ivChatPhoto.getContext()).load(url)
                .override(200, 200)
                .fitCenter()
                .into(ivChatPhoto);
        ivChatPhoto.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void tvIsLocation(int visible){
        if (tvLocation == null)return;
        tvLocation.setVisibility(visible);
    }

}

private CharSequence convertTimestamp(String millis){
    return DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(Long.parseLong(millis), System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Alter your data structure so you do not need to skip rows. This is the best option for long-term performance but if you're just trying to get through a POC, may not be your preference.
2. Don't use FirebaseUI. Use the base Firebase library to run the query yourself. Then post-process the results on the client to remove/omit the rows you don't want. You must return an actual row count to the RecyclerView without those rows you want to omit, and having a clean array of just the rows you DO want is the easiest way to get there.
3. Quick hack: instead of returning `null`, return a 0-height View instead! This is a pretty ugly hack but it does work.